# Is there any effect when placing buildings next to each other?

Tags: supreme-commander

I've noticed that if I place power generators next to factories, little connecting wires appear between the buildings. The AI also likes to build in this fashion, surrounding factories with generators.

Does this have any effect, and if so, what effect? Does the effect depend on what buildings are placed next to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When energy and mass production and storage facilities are placed next to other buildings, they grant a bonus known as **adjacency bonus**. From the Supreme Commander wiki

> - Mass consumption reduction, bestowed by mass production facilities
> - Energy consumption reduction, bestowed by energy production facilities
> - Mass production increase, bestowed by mass storage facilities
> - Energy production increase, bestowed by energy storage facilities.
> - Increased Firing Rate, bestowed by energy producing facilities.

The actual calculation for these bonus are rather complex, but in short, thee bonus encourage you to build storage facilities next to their respective production facilities, and factories and shields close to production facilities. The full list of bonus and how best to use them can be found on the wiki http://supcom.wikia.com/wiki/Adjacency_bonus